# Question regarding ASP.net (web form) architecture

Tags: asp.net

I'm currently working on a ASP.net project that will plug (virtual directory) into a "parent" ASP.net project sort like a module. Since my project have its own Global.asax, web.config, error handling...etc. Would it interfere with the parent project written by someone else? If I'm not mistaking, ASP.net treat each virtual directory as independent so it shouldn't interfering the parent but isn't the flow of the application feel weird and since the whole application will done by different person, won't this approach cause maintenance nightmare if each programmer written differently or in different language.

Comment: Why not just make it a sub directory of the "parent" website?  Are the things in the global.asax, web.config and error handling going to somehow break the parent site?

Answer (score 1):

If you design it to be totally independent module, I don't see any issues.

You might run into some pathing issues if you are referencing some files from the parent web site (like .css, .js or even master pages) if you are not careful.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue you will have is if you want to share session you wont be able to. Other then that you should be fine.

Comment: You can share session across app pool boundaries if you set the machine keys to match.

Answer (score 1):

Your sites will be fine. Be careful of configuration inheritance. Child sites inherit the parent web.config settings.

If it's one application that is a little weird, but if they are all different apps then it is perfectly acceptable to have them in one site. Although breaking them out into their own subdomains would be more preffered:

app1.domain.com
app2.domain.com

If you ever need to scale the apps out, you can put each app on it's own server easily.

While .net has the ability to write in many languages, it's really rare to see anything other than c# or vb. So I wouldn't worry about that too much. Learning different languages is good for you and really helps in becoming a better coder.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily! The need for some sort of version control and weekly code reviews should be sufficient together with close communication between the developers when needed. It depends on the experience on the developers I suppose.